# Jquery Mobile Nested List

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement Jquery Mobile nested list.
I have found this [Example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/lists/lists-nested.html)

On my pc it works fine, but on android devices it doesn't (I have tried on Galaxy S2, Htc Incredible and few others) - the transitions don't work well, when I choose an item on the first list it gets to the third hierarchy etc.

Does anyone here know of an example that works good on actual mobile android devices? Or maybe tried another framework which has better results?

10X!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you have seen uses an old version of the jQuery Mobile framework-Alpha release 4.The latest stable version of jQuery Mobile is 1.0.1.[Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/lists-nested.html) you can see the same example that uses the latest version.Even if the specific issue you are facing is still present with the 1.0.1 version(I could not really check the sample in an android simulator/phone,becaus e I dont have access to both),it is advisable to always use the latest stable version as some issues in the older versions might have been fixed.